# column of type jsonb query by length of array in jsonb

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres table `account_summaries` that has a column `names` of type `jsonb`, which has data in array form, e.g. `['test 1', 'test 2']` and by default has empty array `[]`.

```
id | names
1  | []
2  | ['test 1', 'test 2']
3  | []
```

I can do `select json_agg(names) from account_summaries` and it gives me, for example.

```
json_agg                                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------
 [[], ["test 1", "test 2"], [], [], []]
(1 row)
```

Now, say I want to write a query such that:

1. if the names column is an empty array, return nothing
2. if the names column is not an empty array, return the elements in the column
3. the end result is a 1-dimensional array with the names

So instead I would get

```
json_agg                                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------
 ['test 1', 'test 2']
(1 row)
```

I've tried

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cardinality(jsonb_agg(names))>0 THEN names ELSE NULL END from account_summaries;
```

But it doesn't work.

I'm using Postgres 11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(x) as (values('["a","b"]'::jsonb),('[]'),('["c","d"]'))
select jsonb_agg(j)
from t, jsonb_array_elements(x) as j;

       jsonb_agg
----------------------
 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b9f2dc27d08d266a24e0656e4f1ac17)